# SQL select default value when no results for all values of 'IN' condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of results for a list of users:

```
     table: cdu_user_progress
    ---------------------------------
    |id |uid |duration |date        |
    ---------------------------------
    |1  |1   |20       |1392479414  |
    |2  |1   |30       |1392479414  |
    |3  |2   |20       |1392479345  |
    |4  |3   |40       |1392479812  |
    |5  |2   |20       |1392479994  |
    |6  |2   |60       |1392480100  |
    ---------------------------------
```

I need to get the following results for the most recent week:

```
    -----------------------
    |uid |total_duration  |
    -----------------------
    |1   |0               |
    |2   |60              |
    |3   |0               |
    -----------------------
```

The select I've got is:

```
    SELECT up.uid, SUM(up.duration) AS week_duration, 
    YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(up.date)) AS yearweek 
    FROM cdu_user_progress up 
    WHERE 
    up.uid IN (1,2,3) 
    GROUP BY uid, YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(up.date)) 
    HAVING yearweek = 201411
```

Assume that the only user that has a 'date' in yearweek 201411 is user 2 (record 6).

So I need a default record of 0 to be returned for those users that DON'T have a 'date' in yearweek 201411...

Comment: `YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(up.date))` will make the system ignore indices on that column, which (given it's a major selection/restriction column) is likely to make things slow.  If you have a function that translates yearweek to unix time, you can do something like `up.date >= YEARWEEK_FROM_UNIXTIME(201411) AND up.date < YEARWEEK_FROM_UNIXTIME(201412)`, which means the optimizer can use indices.  This should be in your `WHERE` clause (as `HAVING` means you get all rows, _then_ throw out everything but those rows - wasting a lot of resources).  Constants don't need to be in `GROUP BY`s.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `left join`:

```
SELECT u.uid,
       COALESCE(SUM(up.duration), 0) AS week_duration,
       YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(up.date)) AS yearweek
FROM (SELECT 1 as uid UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) u LEFT JOIN
     cdu_user_progress up
     ON up.uid = u.uid
GROUP BY uid, YEARWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(up.date))
HAVING yearweek = 201411;
```

Comment: It might be good to mention that `u` is being used as a stand-in for a `user` table (or a query that returns "current" users, or something).

Comment: Also, `HAVING`?  Instead of `WHERE`?

Comment: In MySQL, the `having` clause allows you to refer to a column alias.  This is a convenience.  Although less efficient than using a `where`, this is the original form of the OPs query.